# Não consigo compactar nova extensão para o chrome

Tags: google-chrome, extensão

Quando tento compactar uma extensão que estou criando para o Google Chrome, recebo a mensagem abaixo:

**Erro de extensão de pacote**

**Falha ao emitir a chave privada.**

Eu consigo "Carregar sem Compactação" e rodar ele perfeitamente.

Código abaixo:

**popup.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </body>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='./jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='./scripts.js'></script>
</html>
```

**scripts.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('.LoginScreen').length > 0) {
        $("#username").val("usuarioteste");
        $("#password").val("senhateste");
        $("form[name='loginForm'] .DwtButton").click();
    }
});
```

**manifest.json:**

```
{
    "name": "Auto Complete Zimbra",
    "version": "1.1",
    "description": "Extensão para autocompletar e logar automaticamente no Zimbra!",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "favicon.ico",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "*://*.meusite.com.br/*"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "*://*.meusite.com.br/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "jquery.min.js",
                "scripts.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema era que eu estava utilizando em `C:/extensão` e o Chrome tentava criar o arquivo em `C:/`.

Então mudei o local do projeto para uma pasta dentro de `C:/extensão` e ficou `C:/extensões/extensão` e funcionou certinho.

Comment: hoje eu recomendaria chamar de "extensions" e "extension" para evitar o uso de acentuação